# Equal distribution of non-equal area objects in a fixed area

Tags: geometry, contest-math

We are working on a Math problem for our son's school project. We have a question on how to distribute the area among two unequal objects. What would be the correct method to solve this problem

Ex.,I have an overall area of 25 sq/m, and I have two unequal objects of size .35sqm and .4sqm to be equally filled in the overall area. How do we solve this and get the count of the number object 1(.35) and object 2(.4) used in the area? It's okay to have leftover space.

Comment: This is very vague. Do you have a diagram which would add clarity to the problem?

Comment: This sounds like a Packing problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problems. These problems are notoriously hard to solve, even if shapes are of the same size.

Comment: "the number object 1(.35) and object 2(.4) " $\to$ "the number of object$\color{red}{S}$ of type 1 and the number of object$\color{red}{S}$ of type 2"